# Javascript function not called on dynamically created button in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have created button in C# dynamically and added client side event
 but that function not getting called instead getting error as: 
 `Uncaught ReferenceError: setPropertyLocation is not defined`

Javascript:

```
 function setPropertyLocation() {
            alert('Hello');
        }
```

C#:

```
btnMap.Attributes.Add("type", "button");
btnMap.Attributes.Add("title", "Map");
btnMap.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
btnMap.OnClientClick = "setPropertyLocation();return false";
btnMap.ID = "btnMap" + objPMPropTypestructure.PMFields[fieldcnt].SystemName;
btnMap.CssClass = "dataButton";
btnMap.Text = "G";
btnMap.Enabled = true;
tablecell.Controls.Add(btnMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Try to use this.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 document.getElementById ("btnMap").addEventListener ("click", setPropertyLocation, false);
});
```

Comment: How can I add this event as button control created dynamically. I also tried for that but it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: try the modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating this button via JavaScript instead of C#. I assume you are using an update panel. Update panels are a mess. They don't update the DOM elements, they just get rid of the old wrapper and create an entire new, what sets to `undefined` all JavaScript references to any element in that wrapper.

Well, some times we don't have time to refactor the solution, so we must work with what we have.

You may try add an `onclick` attribute to the element, just like you did for `type` and `title` attribtues.